# DB2 remove empty lines

Tags: db2

I have strings like this

```
#
word_1
word_2
#
word_3
#
#
```

where # represents empty lines.
I'd like to remove those empty lines, for getting

```
word_1
word_2
word_3
```

I've tried replacing CHR(10) and CHR(13) with '' but then I get

```
word_1word_2word_3
```

I've seen I can remove the first empty line using LTRIM, but how to get rid of all of them?

Comment: What's your code and your system? Is that for storing values or returning it to some form of client?

Comment: I'm on windows and I'm extracting those data with a query

Comment: Please add that information, including your query, to the question.

Comment: I use IBM Data Studio 4.1.2 and the query is just `select column from table`..And as I said, the other ones I've tried are `select LTRIM(column, CHR(10) || CHR(13)) from table` and `select replace(replace(column, CHR(10),''), CHR(13),'') from table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove all new-line characters followed by new-line character, and a single new-line character at the start and the end of a string. All these replacements can be done with a single expression.

## Starting from v11.1

```
select regexp_replace (s, '\r\n(?=\r\n)|^\r\n|\r\n$', '')
from (values x'0d0a' || 'abc' || x'0d0a0d0a'|| 'def' || x'0d0a') t (s)
```

Note, that you may have a new-line character encoded as `x'0a'` instead of `x'0d0a'`. Remove all the `\r` characters in this case from the expression above.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=76d7de67d72286fcc4630ef4dccf725d) link.

## Starting from v9.7

```
select xmlcast (xmlquery ('replace (replace ($d, "^\r\n|\r\n$", ""), "(\r\n){2,}", "$1")' passing s as "d") as varchar (100))
from (values x'0d0a' || 'abc' || x'0d0a0d0a'|| 'def' || x'0d0a') t (s)
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=0563f28ba093777ea35a0659ea7267e4) link.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I'm on DB2 v.10.5 and I guess 'REGEXP_REPLACE' is newer, since I got the error 'No authorized routine named "REGEXP_REPLACE" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found'...

Comment: I added an example for older db2 versions.

Comment: Thanks. I must feel very stupid, but should I write my column instead of that 's' in 'passing s'? I'm speaking of that 9.7 query..

Comment: Yes. Write your column name instead of `s`.

Comment: Marvellous, you are the man! Thank you so much